# How can I declare a matrix in javascript using good practices?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I was trying to declare a matrix in Javascript and I've found myself using different ways without having knowledge if those ones are the correct ones, does that make sense? So, I did research about it and I found some ways to declare it through different posts, but I was wondering which one might be a good practice... So, someone knows which one could be a good example of declaring a matrix following good practices in Javascript?

Comment: maybe you can share what you have found and list them in your question.

Comment: There is no good or bad way, it really comes down to your style of programming. Some will prefer using loop, and other will prefer using Array function such as `fill`. I personally prefer using array functions since it reduce the code needed to do a task but in the end it's the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that's true @Nicolas I agree with you.

Comment: @Siavash sorry about that I think I should have shared a few examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic for-loop to create a matrix:

```
var matrix = new Array(N);
for(var i=0; i<N; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(N);
}
```

Or, you can use Array.fill() method:

```
var matrix = Array(N).fill(Array(N));
```

Comment: Oh, dude! I like the second option looks cleaner the first one. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```js
var multiArray = [
  [
    [1, 1],
    [1, 2]
  ],
  [
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2]
  ]
];

for (var i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < multiArray[i][j].length; k++) {
      console.log(multiArray[i][j][k]);
    }
  }
}
```